# Webpack resolve a directory for import paths (goCardless as a boiletplate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, webpack, require

Currently a typical component will look like the below code. Note that using the paths to the file has become problematic and ugly. Moving a file causes massive issues with updating paths across multiple components.

This truly takes away from the component based experience when a path change can break everything and cause mass find and replace of paths.

In an ideal world the displayName would be the import reference and searched for within the directory.

```
'use strict';

//libs
import React from 'react';

//components
import TopFeatures from '../../headphones/subcomponents/top-features';
import Prices from './prices';
import Image from '../../layout/image';
import InlineRatingElement from '../../reviews/rating';

//helpers
import { getImageUrl } from '../../helpers/app/image';
import { initiateInlineRatings } from '../../helpers/app/inline-ratings';

export default class HDOverview extends React.Component {
  displayName = 'HDOverview'

  static propTypes = {
    vendor: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        JSX
      </div>
   );
  }
}
```

I am looking to do something like this:

```
import TopFeatures from 'TopFeatures';//TopFeatures is the displayName
import Prices from 'Prices'; //Prices is the displayName etc.
import Image from 'Image';
import InlineRatingElement from 'InlineRatingElement';

//helpers
import { getImageUrl } from 'ImageHelper';
import { initiateInlineRatings } from 'InlineRatingHelper';
```

Webpack has a great tutorial on resolve aliases here: http://xabikos.com/javascript%20module%20bundler/javascript%20dependencies%20management/2015/10/03/webpack-aliases-and-relative-paths.html

However this insinuates that the path to the component would need to be logged in one place - in an ideal world there would be a way to dynamically check paths / directories to find the displayName that matches. Note that we have 200 components, so manually creating that list is do-able but sizable.

Having looked around I have seen people using

> require("components!/layout/image")

however we would like to stick to the import technique and not go back to require.

Any suggestions or advice are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is, unfortunately, a limitation of `node`, `npm`.

There are workarounds to get absolute/mapped paths to work in npm but all of these have drawbacks: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Another option is individual npm packages for each component, but this adds a lot of overhead.